# Unable to deploy my Jupyter Notebook to Medium as a post

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to publish a Jupyter Notebook as a medium blog, I installed all the necessary libraries, then I put in my integration token too, and every other detail, including the correct file path directory.

So after installing jupyter_to_medium package, I opened the notebook I wished to publish and selected the option File -> Deploy as -> Medium Post, but I am getting this error :

```
Failed to post to Medium
Returned error message below
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Downloads\\\\impact_evaluation_analytics.ipynb'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\nbformat\\__init__.py\", line 165, in read
buf = fp.read()
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_bundler.py\", line 71, in upload
data = publish(**kwargs)
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_publish_to_medium.py\", line 432, in publish
p = Publish(
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_publish_to_medium.py\", line 60, in __init__
self.nb = self.get_notebook()
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_to_medium\\_publish_to_medium.py\", line 114, in get_notebook
return nbformat.read(self.filename, as_version=4)
File \"C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\nbformat\\__init__.py\", line 167, in read
with open(fp, encoding=\"utf-8\") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Downloads\\\\impact_evaluation_analytics.ipynb
```

Comment: I think the major hint is here: `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Downloads\\\\impact_evaluation_analytics.ipynb'`